# Word Mailing: Cross reference if merge-field paragraph number

Tags: cpu-word, cross-reference, mailing

I have a sophisticated legal document template that contains numbered paragraphs with numbered subparagraphs on a different level.

Many of these paragraphs are contained within if...else statements.

The problem is when I try to add a cross-reference to one of these possible subparagraphs, I've got a blank. If I add a cross-reference to the text content, it does pull.

Is there a way to solve it?

[image: Template]

[image: Generated Document]

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cross-reference-if-merge-field-paragraph-number/c03eb62a-a09f-4622-8519-0f7317af0923. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184. Furthermore, this is not a programming question; it is an end-user question. As such, it is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi, it is a cross-posted question, my colleague and I are working on the same issue.  
I tried your link, but it didn't work. Is it prohibited to ask the same question on StackOverflow? Besides, I can say that it is a programming question. I'm trying to update the word document from code using Aspose library for .net

Comment: The links work when I click on them. The problem is that you can end up wasting peoples' time. Those who ignore such courtesies soon find that no-one will help them on any forum. Your reference to "trying to update the word document from code using Aspose library for .net" could be an important consideration in the other thread.